# npm install expo-cli --global

Tags: xserver, npm

error 1
core-js@2.6.11 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.11 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

[image]

Comment: Please use only relevant tags. Please post terminal output as text (formatted as code), **not** as an image. And please ask an actual question.

Comment: please resolve my error ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

please add your file name .watchmanconfig resolve the problem